# Java (Eclipse): Trying to access a class.main with (String args[])

Tags: string, class, return, program-entry-point, args

I've got a problem: I can go fine between classes in my Elipse java project, if they are like this

```
public class Comienzo {
    public static void main() {}
}
```

But not if they're like this

```
public class Principal {    
    public static void main(String args[]) {}
}
```

I'm yet noobish programmer, so I'm not sure if this is about `String args[]`, but if I delete them Eclipse tell me something's wrong and string args are needed.

So I'm with my class Principal, click a button and

```
Comienzo.main();
```

moves from Principal to Comienzo, but if I press a cancel button on Comienzo, I'd like to go back to Principal, but that's the problem, I can't do

```
Principal.main(String args[]);
```

because in Comienzo class string cannot be resolved into a variable, and well, I'm not sure what path should I take to go back to Principal class.

*Thanks for the comments, the answer is inside the comments.*

Comment: `main( String args[] )` is called when the program starts. You should not be calling it once the program has started (meaning the code you write should not explicitly call it).

Comment: if you really want to call `main( String args[] )` you can do it as follows `main(new String[]{});`

Comment: `main(String args[])`is the first function called at the begining of a program; it does not belong to any class (even if it looks like so in the code). If you want to launch a function from a class, you need to create a "constructor" function. I would advise you to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) in order to get familiar with Object Oriented programming.

Comment: @Rems yes it does belong to a class. It doesn't belong to an instance of the class.

Comment: @clcto Oh yes you're right, my bad: It's `static`. But yet it doesn't act as a constructor, does it? From what I understoody, you still have to build a constructor for the class `main()` is in (if of course it's not static).

Comment: @Rems no, it is not a constructor. Whether or not the class needs a constructor is another question all together. For example, a simple `HelloWorld` program definitely does not need a constructor.

Comment: @clcto Ok, that's what I thought. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, problem solved, I'm able to call a class from another and restart the program with the main(new String[]{});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to call `main( String args[] )` you can do it as follows `main(new String[]{});`